# Facebook Like button og:image needs to be scraped to be displayed

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I've got a Drupal website with articles on them which have Facebook like buttons.

Now I've got all the OpenGraph metatags added on the pages and it's all working perfectly except for one thing.

Site visitors can share a page URL or like a page URL.
When a new article is added and the first person who presses the like button will not see the image added in the `og:image` tag.

If another person afterwards presses the like button, the `og:image` however is visible so it seems to me Facebook needs to scrape the page first before the `og:image` is added in the 'Facebook Like window'.

The Facebook share doesn't seem to suffer from this problem and does it right from the first time.

Now whenever somebody adds a new article, I'd need the URL of the article to be scraped automatically by Facebook using some PHP code or some other fix...

Anyone who knows if autoscraping a URL is possible or does anyone have an idea for a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the graph API with `scrape=true` to force Facebook to scrape you right when you create your contents

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/objects/

Comment: The act of a user clicking your Like button should cause Facebook to scrape your page for OG metadata before it adds it to the user's Timeline, so it's odd that you're seeing this problem. Paul's suggestion should fix your problem, though.